# Assign new class variable without use of a constructor?

Tags: php, oop

I want to know if I can somehow assign new variable without making constructor.

It seems pretty big overkill to create constructors on every class just to set initial private class variables.

Here is my example of what I want to achieve

```
<?php

class MyClass {
    public function DoSomething() {
        echo '1';
    }
}

class MySecondClass {
    private $obj = new MyClass(); // Error

    /*
        // This works, but I don't like it, I think it's total overkill
        function __construct() {
            $this->obj = new MyClass();
        }
    */

    public function PrintOne() {
        $this->obj->DoSomething();
    }
}

$class = new MySecondClass();
$class->PrintOne();
```

Just so it's perfectly clear here's the error message

> syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) on line 10

Comment: You can't initialize a class variable to the result of a run-time call, you can only use static values. Your constructor method is just fine.

Comment: It is the whole purpose of a constructor to setup initial variables. Why do you consider it to be overkill?

Comment: @dev-null-dweller Coming from `C#` I am used to not doing that. That's all, no particular reason whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't (that I know of), you *need* to either instantiate it in the constructor (Option A), or pass in the object (Option B).

Option A:

```
class MySecondClass {
    private $obj;

    function __construct() {
       $this->obj = new MyClass();
    }

    public function PrintOne() {
        $this->obj->DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Option B:

```
class MySecondClass {
    private $obj;

    function __construct(MyClass $obj) {
       $this->obj = $obj;
    }

    public function PrintOne() {
        $this->obj->DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Steve: Just a note. Option B is generally better.

Comment: @Steve , you might want to watch [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEhu57pih5w).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in that manner.  You can have properties be initialized but they need to be a constant value and not the result of a function or trying to instantiate a class.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

IMO, You shouldn't instantiate new objects within the constructor of your classes.  You should pass them in as arguments for creating the object.